# How to implement something like control.begininvoke in C# for C++？

Tags: c#, multithreading, mfc, win32gui

Since our MFC-based application involves many computations in worker threads, I want to write something like `Control.BeginInvoke` of WindowsForm in C++ to simplify development.

And I want to leverage some modern interfaces like `std::bind` and `std::function`. My expectation is something like:

```
void UIHandler(Param1 const&, Param2 const &);

void WorkerFunc()
{
      // blahblah
      asyncagent.begininvoke(&UIHandler,  p1, p2);
}
```

I know basic multithread programming rules, so I want to implement it using `PostMessage`, but I don't know how to proceed.

My concern is:

1. How to transfer big data between threads, and avoid memory and resource leaks. Because if I `new` something and post it to the UI thread, but the target window is gone, the memory leaks.
2. I want some easy interfaces, which don't force inheritance. Better use just as easy as a member variable, say,  `AsyncAgent ag`, in our UI class, and init it in constructor.

Can somebody shed some light please? Is there something like this exists so I don't have to invent wheels or I must write it the hard way?

Thanks.

Comment: `Control.BeginInvoke` posts a window message to itself, adds the delegate to a queue. Once the message posted received, it just invokes the delegate. For more info look into the source.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thanks. You mean use something like reflector to study it? I will look into it.

Comment: Not really required, [microsoft has made source public for reference](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/ndp/fx/src/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs#92512f20d564f18e#references)